# Detect Admin in frontpage of Opencart 2.3

Tags: php, session, admin, opencart2.x, detect

For whole day I'm trying to find a way to detect that you are logged as Admin in backend while you are displaying the front page. ( Opencart v 2.3 ). Non of advices that i have found today works.. Is there any way to do that?
It would be great if there was a function like in Wordpress is_admin()..

Comment: In Wordpress, all users are users, with different levels of access. In Opencart, there are 3 different types of users (users, customers, affiliates), which are each completely independent of one another. For instance, a WP user with commenting privileges can be upgraded to posting privileges by a simple permission change. In Opencart, an account can exist in the customer table, but it's only a customer - it's not in the user table. Likewise, a user can have their account to admin the site but its different than the account for buying products.

Comment: Short version - opencart users and WP users are completely different from one another.

Comment: Once again. The question is: How to detect admin on the frontpage? Lets get to the point.

Comment: Look in your session array for `user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be in same browser.
Now go to any controller and insert the code to check if user_id is set in the session.
For example:
Go to catalog/controller/common/header.php

Inside the index() method add following code:

```
    if($this->session->data['user_id']){
        echo 'Admin is logged in';
    }else{
        echo 'Admin is not logged in';
    }
```

Another way initialize the user object and check with isLogged() method

```
    $loggeduser = new Cart\User($this->registry);
    if($loggeduser->isLogged()){
        echo "Admin is in";
    }else{
        echo "Admin not in";
    }
```

https://webocreation.com/blog/check-admin-logged-front-page-opencart-2-3

Comment: Great! It's working with the second way. Thank you very much!

Comment: However, I still wonder how to use this data inside header.tpl. I was trying to do it something like this: [link]http://pastebin.com/NbpT1b5J and it gives me: `Admin is in Notice: Undefined variable: bigBoss in C:\wamp64\www\xxx\catalog\view\theme\OPC080193_6\template\common\header.tpl on line 93`

Comment: I also tried to add `$this->session->data['bigBoss'] = 1;` inside the header.php and call it `<?php 
echo $this->session->data['bigBoss'];
?>` inside the header.tpl but I recive: `Notice: Undefined property: Template\PHP::$session in C:\wamp64\www\itw\catalog\view\theme\OPC080193_6\template\common\header.tpl on line 96Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\itw\catalog\view\theme\OPC080193_6\template\common\header.tpl on line 96`

Comment: In controller please do like below, need to be set into the data object.
------------------------------------------------------------------
if($loggeduser->isLogged()){
                    echo "Admin is in";
                    $data['bigBoss']= 1;
                }else{
                    echo "Admin not in";
                    $data['bigBoss'] = 0;
                }
------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: After that, when i'm placing in header.tpl <body> `<?php echo $data['bigBoss']; ?>` it gives me:  `Notice: Undefined variable: data` :(

Comment: :) In template file, <body> just use <?php echo $bigBoss; ?>

Comment: Boom! Thank You a lot! :)